i have a problem in connect firebase at project flutter on andriod studio
when connecting firebase at the project flutter in step flutterfire configure said me flutterfire not found despite of all steps true and last step write me installed executable flutterfire


Did you add the flutterfire command to your path? When you install the flutterfire CLI (with dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli) the last step in the output says how to do that (at least, that's what it does on my mac).

After you install and activate flutterfire_cli, your terminal would suggest you to add flutterfire to the path based on your OS and shell (bash, zsh etc)
For linux bash, suggestion code would look like
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
Just run it as per your path.
